# Progress Bar can not be hidden

Tags: android

I have been trying to add a progress bar to my app that shows up when login button is clicked.
My problem is that I can't seem to hide the progress bar.
I tried setting `pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);` but it isn't working. Android Studio doesn't show any error. Progress bar simply stays visible always.

Also, at first everything was running perfectly, this problem came up after I added a navigation drawer activity in my application and I am sending an intent to the login activity through that.
Is sending intent cause of the problem?

### activity_login.xml

This is how I have added progress bar in xml.

```
<ProgressBar
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:id="@+id/progressBarLogin"
    android:indeterminateTint="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

### LoginActivity.java

This is how i am trying to hide it

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ProgressBar pBar;
Button login;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    pBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBarLogin);

    pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE); //THIS LINE OF CODE IS NOT WORKING

    login = findViewById(R.id.login);  
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });

            try{
                //Background login tasks
            }catch(Exception e){
                pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

EDIT- For all those people who are pointing out about `pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);` being in the catch block and hence not running, that piece of code is running perfectly fine. Problem is that when I try to hide `pbar` at the start, that line simply doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Your catch block is not calling

Comment: You don't have anything on try block, how will it go to `catch` block and `setVisibility` to `GONE`?

Comment: In thread, it will not run or will not run smoothly. Try asynctask.

Comment: I do have code in try block. Just for the sake of this question i replaced the code with comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `pBar.setVisibility(View.Gone)` it will hide your progress bar. If progress bar is still visible .

**Temporary Solution**

Put your `Progress Bar` in `Layout` and hide the layout by using `Layout.setVisiblity(View.GONE)`

Answer (score 2):

Try adding below line in `try` block after completing your background task (i.e) moving to another activity,

```
pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

inside `try` block.

Comment: or alternatively we can have this block of code in finally block

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
android:visibility = "gone"
```

in the xml file.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write `pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);` under the try block

Answer (score 0):

Remove try catch block.

then try to run...it will work... 100%

or

put try & catch block code inside the run method....it will work....
i am already checked this.... it is working fine...

Answer (score 0):

Try add `android:visibility="invisible"` to you .xml file. Or may be you see progress bar from other activity?

Answer (score -1):

Progress bar is view but you have to close it after few time or task. In your code its only visible and close in catch which is wrong might be catch will not execute. so if you want to show and close then you have to firstly make it visible and after few sec call method to gone or invisible.

```
pBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
     new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {          
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // this code will be executed after 2 seconds 
pBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);      
        }
    }, 2000);
```

Hope it will help.